# django many to many filtering based on user

Tags: django, many-to-many

Let's say I have a 2 models, Library and Book, Book has a many to many relation to Library (in the sense that various libraries can have the book). Now the Library model has a many to many relation to Users (the user can have various library cards).
How can I query the database to retrieve all the books available to a certain user?
An example would look like this: I have 3 libraries and the user has a card in 1 and 2 but not 3. So the query would list all books that have a relation to library 1 and 2, avoiding duplicates.

right now I'm trying with:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(libraries__members=user).distinct()
```

is this right?

Comment: Run `django-admin.py shell` and execute that line and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not stating it, I indeed tested it and it returns what I am waiting for. But this piece of code comes from my understanding of how many to many works, not from the docs or any trusted source. I don't know if it's the best way to do it or if there are drawbacks to this one (I tested on a new database, without many books or libraries).